Solution of $V'(t)=AV(t)+V(t)A^T+\sigma^2I_m$, where $A$ is the discretized Neumann-Laplacian
I'm considering a PDE involving the Laplacian on $[0,1)^2$. I'm discretizing the problem using the finite difference approach. The resolution discretized Laplcian opertor $A$ with Neumann boundary conditions is of the form as in the picture below:

with $h=1$. For this I need to solve the equation $$V'(t)=AV(t)+V(t)A^T+\sigma^2I_m$$ with $V(0)=0$, where $\sigma>0$. Do I need to solve this numerically (if so, how should I do it?) or can we even give the explicit solution in this case?
EDIT: My hope is that we can solve the equation analytically, given the simple shape of $A$ (which especially does not depend on time). If not, I'm hoping that there is at least a faster and/or more accurate way to solve this than using Euler.

Something is wrong here. Is $V(t) \in \mathbb{R}^{N\times 1}$? If yes, what is $V(t) A^T$ ($ \mathbb{R}^{N\times 1} \times  \mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$)?

@NN2 No, $V(t)\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$.

For an analytic solution you will at least need to know matrix exponentials of some of these matrices which seems difficult to obtain. Any stiff solver should be able to handle it numerically though. E.g. backwards Euler, implicit Runge Kutta methods, Rosenbrock, BDF

Define $V^{k}$ be the approximated solution of $V(t_k)$ on a grid $0= x_0<x_1<\dots<x_{n-1} = 1-h$, such that the mesh size is $h$ and the time step size is $\Delta t$ (at every time you march using the following). Now your $V^k = (V^k_j)^n_{j=1}$ should be an $n\times 1$ vector $V^k_j \approx V(t_k, x_j)$
The safest bet is the backward Euler which is $A$-stable:
$$
\frac{V^{k+1} - V^k}{\Delta t} = AV^{k+1}+V^{k+1}A^T+\sigma^2I_m
$$
and solve for ${V^{k+1}}$ in this problem with $V^0 = \mathbf{0}$.

Sorry, I wasn't able to come back to this until now. I've actually implemented a forward Euler scheme, but it gave bad results. How would I implement this backward Euler scheme here? I'm using the Eigen library and don't see a way to solve it with that. If you know, I'd highly appreciate!

I'm only able to solve this when I replace one of the $V^{k+1}$ on the rhs of your equation by $V^k$.

@0xbadf00d you have to move every term that involves $V^{k+1}$ to the left, then call a linear solver to solve the linear system.
